# Is there a penalty for mixing color spaces? (Core Graphics)

Tags: iphone, macos, core-graphics, cgcolorspace

If I'm writing drawing code in Core Graphics on Mac OS X or iPhone OS, I can set the active fill color to red by calling:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // RGB(1,0,0)
```

If I want 50% gray, I *could* call:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0); // RGB(0.5,0.5,0.5)
```

But for shades of gray it's tempting to make a shorter line and call:

```
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.5, 1.0);
```

However, this function is NOT simply calling the RGB method with the intensity value copied three times; instead it is changing the context's color space from DeviceRGB to DeviceGray. The next call to an RGB method will switch it back.

I'm curious to know:

- What's the penalty for switching color spaces?
- Is there a penalty for drawing when your context's color space doesn't match your device's native color space? (i.e., drawing in DeviceGray versus DeviceRGB)

I'm asking out of technical curiosity, not a desire to prematurely optimize, so please keep your admonitions to a minimum, please.

Comment: No idea whether it's faster, but couldn't you test it by building a test project which tests this? One run would test filling by using the same color space all the time, and the other would switch between color spaces. I would guess that if there is a penalty, it is in converting the color values from your color space to the bitmap's color space, but the difference would be negligible between tests.

Comment: Yeah, at this point I plan to write some test code when I have the time. I was waiting to get a Tumbleweed badge first, but it looks like my question isn't quite uninteresting enough.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, there's a penalty, but in practice it's so miniscule as to be irrelevant; converting (e.g.) a shade of gray to an RGB triplet (plus alpha) is trivial arithmetic even with a custom colour space.

Colour spaces *do* have a penalty when you're drawing images, however, as it's more than a matter of a single conversion operation. Every pixel must be converted, and while there are optimizations that can be done here (e.g. CLUTs, Colour Look-Up Tables, are useful if the source image uses indexed colours) they don't tend to be useful in situations where you also find Quartz code.

You say you expect `CGContextSetGrayFillColor()` to change the colour space of the graphics context, but that isn't actually the case. Doing so would necessitate converting the contents of that graphics context to match the context's new colour space. Since it's far cheaper and simpler to convert the colour instead of the context's buffers (e.g. by making `CGContextSetGrayFillColor()` an under-the-covers wrapper around `CGContextSetRGBFillColor()`), such an expense is going to be avoided in any sensible implementation.

Comment: The documentation [clearly states](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetRGBFillColor) that the `CGContextSet*Color()` functions change the context's color space. But I don't think that is the same as changing the color space of the buffer you are drawing into, though.

Comment: No, it says they set the *fill* or *stroke* colour spaces--the colour spaces in which your passed `CGFloat` values form a colour coordinate. That just means that, when you then provide the R, G, B, A, or whatever values you passed, they're interpreted correctly.

The context's colour space, if it can be thought of as having one, always matches the colour space of the destination; having the two not match would be nonsensical. :)

See the docs for `CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace()` and `CGContextSetFillColorSpace()`--these funcs all ultimately wrap around one of those & `CGContextSetFillColor()`.

Comment: (Or around `CGContextSetStrokeColor()` as appropriate. Ran out of room.)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using both extensively in a similar manner and have noticed no penalty in terms of performance.

Comment: I imagine any difference in performance is below the threshold of "noticing".

Comment: Yes. However, the proper way is to run benchmarks if you think that there might be a performance penalty. From experience, I can tell you that only methods/properties that directly draw on the screen (or affect drawing) may have a penalty e.g. adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. This may not always be apparent.